# Using RegEx to find and print plural words in Turkish

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am fairly new in python. In the code, I've read a text file as input, and put each line readen on this text file into a list as elements.

I'm trying to write the code using RegEx to find and print plural words. In turkish, plural words are '-ler' or '-lar' suffixes.

my code is as follows:

```
import re

f = open('C:/Users/ENE/Desktop/CSE & Kodlar/nlp/utf8textfile.txt', encoding='utf-8-sig', errors='ignore')


with f as file:
    list = file.readlines()
list = [x.strip() for x in list]

print(list)

total = 0
for i in list:
    total += len(i)
ave_size = float(total) / float(len(list))
print("Average word length = " + str(ave_size))

#p = re.compile('.*l[ae]r.*')

for element in list:
    m = re.findall(".*l[ae]r.*", element)
    if m:
        print(m)
```

which gives an output of

list = ['Aliler geldiler', 'Selam olsun sana', 'Merhabalar', 'Java kitabı nerede']

for loop:
['Aliler geldiler']
['Merhabalar']

I am trying to print word by word, like ['Aliler'], ['geldiler'] and ['Merhabalar']. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just find all words ending in `lar` or `ler` using a `\w*l[ea]r\b` regex:

```
results = re.findall(r'\w*l[ea]r\b', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TazRWw/2). In Python 3.x, `\b` word boundary is Unicode aware by default, in Python 2.x, I'd recommend adding `re.U` flag.

Here, `s` can be the whole line, or even the whole document.

**Details**

- `\w*` - 0+ letters, digits and `_` (in Python 3.x, it will match all Unicode letters, digits or `_`, you may use `[^\W\d_]*` to only match letters)
- `l` - an `l` letter
- `[ea]` - `e` or `a`
- `r` - an `r` letter
- `\b` - a word boundary (note the `r'..'` notation used to avoid double escaping `\b` to make the engine parse it as a word boundary).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want with the following:

```
import re

example = "example words Aliler Merhabalar"

words = example.split()

for word in words:
    if (re.search(r"ler$", word)):
        print (word)
    elif (re.search(r"lar$", word)):
        print (word)
```

This will output:

```
Aliler
Merhabalar
```

Comment: Why ***two*** searches?

Answer (score 0):

`.*` matches everything (except line terminators).

This means that `.*l[ae]r.*` will make entire input, if it contains `lar` or `ler`, and will otherwise match nothing.

You want to match words, not entire lines.

Since the word must end with `l[ae]r`, you need to ensure that the `r` is the end of the word. That can be done using `\b` (word boundary).

Since the word must end with `l[ae]r`, it has to be prededed by 1 or more (`+`) word characters, i.e. `\w`.

Now, `\w` only matches ASCII letters (A-Z), so you need to enable Unicode mode, so it matches all letters (e.g. [`ñ`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00f1/index.htm) and [`ı`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0131/index.htm)). Also note that `\w` matches digits (0-9) and underscore (_), but that's generally ok.

So, your regex should be:

```
r"\w+l[ae]r\b"u
```

See [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/mmWRP4/1) for demo.